# Detecting collision with a child of a node and another node in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So I created a parent node named planet, that has to two children one of which is a 'landingPad'. I'm trying to detect collision between this child and another node named 'lander'. I've tried a lot of options but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

```
  func createPlanet() {
    var planet = SKSpriteNode()
    planet.zPosition = 1
    planet.name = "mars"

    redPlanet = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "redPlanet")
    redPlanet.name = "red"
    redPlanet.zPosition = 2
    planet.addChild(redPlanet)

    landingPad = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "landingPad")
    landingPad.name = "pad"
    landingPad.zPosition = 3
    landingPad.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: redPlanet.size.height / 2 - 60)
    landingPad.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: landingPad.texture!, size: size)
    landingPad.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    landingPad.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = landingPadMask
    landingPad.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = landerMask
    landingPad.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
    planet.addChild(landingPad)

    planet.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: -redPlanet.size.height / 6)
    planet.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: redPlanet.size.height / 2)
    planet.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
    planet.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = planetMask
    planet.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0

    let spinner = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 3)
    planet.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(spinner))

    addChild(planet)
  }
```

And the lander code...

```
  func createLander() {
    var randomX = RandomInt(min: 10, max: 400)

    lander = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "lander")
    lander.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomX), y: frame.size.height + 20)
    lander.name = "lander"
    lander.zPosition = 10


    lander.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: lander.texture!, size: lander.size)
    lander.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    lander.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    lander.physicsBody!.friction = 0.2
    lander.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.75
    lander.physicsBody!.linearDamping = 0.208
    lander.physicsBody!.angularDamping = 0.1
    lander.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = landerMask
    lander.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = landingPadMask | cometMask

    addChild(lander)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing:

```
lander.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = landingPadMask | cometMask
```

and

```
landingPad.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = landerMask
```

And for the delegate:

```
self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;
```

Then you get the collision with:

`didBeginContact` and `didEndContact`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. I already had the delegate and didBeginContact, but I added the rest. Still wasn't working, the lander would run into an invisible node, but fixed it by changing the SKPhysics(texture... to SKPhysics(rectangleOfSize... for the landingPad. Now I need to get the spinning planet to stop on contact. RemoveAllActions() doesn't appear to work. I'll start a new thread. Cheers.